# I created a login page but after clicking on the login button it doesn't redirect to the page i want it to redirect to it just refreshes the same page

Tags: php, html, database, authentication, localhost

Here's the code i wrote for the page.

Instead of it redirecting to dashboard.php it just refreshes the login page.

[screenshot one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfyUq.png)
[screenshot two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3SCg.png)

I want the page to redirect the user to the dashboard after clicking on the "login" button and after inputting correct data. Instead, it just refreshes the same login page over and over.

I entered the code here, but i just kept on getting errors. Guess I can't post the php codes here. Screenshot One is the php code.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
<div class="col-lg-7"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="right_part space-y-20">
                <h1 class="color_white"> Welcome to Exodus </h1>
                <p class="color_white" style="color: white !important">Don't have an account yet? <a href="../register/index.php"> Register </a>
                </p>
                <form action="http://localhost/exodusdesign.io/login/index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="nL0pZB9uxAlOnQsrkzJ4r8MlML79n8D6oZZvvoOeyUNTv5JT5ekOfymsZktEkgWX">
                    <div class="box edit_box w-full space-y-20">
                        <div class="space-y-10">
                            <span class="nameInput">Username </span>
                            <div class="confirm">
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="space-y-10">
                            <span class="nameInput">Password</span> 
                            <div class="confirm">
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="color_black" >Forgot Password? <a href="../password-reset/index.php"> Click here </a>
                                                    <!-- <a href="/password-reset/" class="btn btn-white btn-sm color_green"> Forgot Password? </a> -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-grad w-full btn-lg mt-3"> Login</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="Login">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) You can post PHP code here.

Comment: did you put dashboard.php in the same folder as index.php you used for login process?

Comment: Never store plain text passwords!

Answer (score 0):

1. In form action, write action=""
2. In line no. 20, check if button is clicked, by replacing following code : `if($_POST){ // logic }`
3. In the logic, echo something for testing, if it works, then replace your code.
4. If it still not works, then at the top of the page, put following code : `<?php ob_start(); ?>`
5. Make sure dashboard.php and login.php are in the same folder.

Comment: In Step 4, Write the code : <?php ob_start(); ?> at the top of the page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I fixed this already.  Thank you all.